# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am getting this error when I am running my visualforce page

Below is my apex extension class:
    public with sharing class ExtensionAccount {

```
    public ExtensionAccount(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }
    private final Account acct;  

    // The constructor passes in the standard controller defined
    // in the markup below
    public ExtensionAccount(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        this.acct = (Account)controller.getRecord(); 
    }    

    public ApexPages.StandardSetController TaskRecords {
        get {
            if(TaskRecords == null) {
                TaskRecords = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(
                    Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT AccountId FROM Task Where WhatId IN 
                        (Select id From Opportunity Where AccountId = :acct.Id)]));
            }
            return TaskRecords ;
        }
        private set;
    }
    public List<Task> getTaskList() {
         return (List<Task>) TaskRecords.getRecords();
    }  
}
```

Visualforce page

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="ExtensionAccount" sidebar="false"> 
<apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity"> 
<apex:pageBlockSection > 
<apex:dataList value="{!TaskList}" var="task" type="1"> {!task.accountid} </apex:dataList> 
</apex:pageBlockSection> 
</apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: code looks good to me. Are you passing Account Id in url ?

Comment: Account should be initialized in constructor. And from where are you getting `acct.Id`?

Comment: <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="ExtensionAccount" sidebar="false">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity">
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:dataList value="{!TaskList}" var="task" type="1">
                    {!task.accountid}
                </apex:dataList>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
      
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>

Comment: this is my visualforce page

Comment: @RachitJoshi You need to pass account Id in url

Comment: https://c.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/MyExtensionPage?id=00128000007AKRy still getting same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using single account id then add `this.acct = (Account)controller.getRecord();` in your `StandardController`

```
public ExtensionAccount(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
       this.acct = (Account)controller.getRecord(); //Add this line
    }
    private final Account acct;  

    // The constructor passes in the standard controller defined
    // in the markup below
    public ExtensionAccount(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        this.acct = (Account)controller.getRecord(); 
    }
```

---

Edit

```
 public ExtensionAccount(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
      this.acct = (Account)controller.getRecord();
    }
    private final Account acct;  

    // The constructor passes in the standard controller defined
    // in the markup below
    public ExtensionAccount(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        this.acct = (Account)controller.getRecord(); 
    }    


    public List<Task> getTaskList() {
         return [SELECT AccountId FROM Task Where WhatId IN (Select id From Opportunity Where AccountId = :acct.Id)];
    }  
}
```

Comment: The error is gone.

Comment: Visualforce Error
Help for this Page

List controllers are not supported for Task

Comment: now i am geting this error

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: Database.Query(List<Task>) at line 16 column 17

Comment: @RachitJoshi Just remove database.query .. check my updated ans

Comment: @RachitJoshi welcome

Comment: could you provide me test class for this

Comment: I am not able to make one

Comment: @RachitJoshi Pls dn't ask to write test class. First try to write test class by yourself. While writing if you face any issue ask another question with error we will help you

Comment: i was just getting an error while creating one.

Comment: But It's solved now.

Comment: Thanks. I was just trying to compare my class with the one you create